# SQL query running in SQL Server but not in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am running query in SQL Server and it's running fine and returning data:

```
 var record = DbContext.Attendances
                       .SqlQuery("select id, checktype, locationinfo, latitude, longitude, employeeid, 
                                         activityid, DateNTime at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'pakistan standard time' as datentime " +
                                 "from(select *, CONVERT(varchar, DateNTime at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'pakistan standard time', 101) as tb from dbo.Attendances where EmployeeId = 3) as t "+
                                 "where tb = '03/05/2022'");
```

Exact same query is not working when I run it in the ASP.NET MVC app using `.SqlQuery` function. It gave me an error:

> The 'DateNTime' property on 'Attendance' could not be set to a 'System.DateTimeOffset' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.

Although I set DateNTime non-nulable.

Here is my table:

[image]

I cannot change `DateTime` to `DateTime?` because then I will have to change the code in many places.

Comment: Your query looks odd, look at "DateNTime at time zone 'utc' at time zone 'pakistan standard time' as  datentime ", also why are you using SELECT .... FROM(SELECT...), why not just SELECT * FROM Attendance. The error message says that you are trying to set DateNTime to a DateTimeOffset when it requires a datetime. Do you have an update somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Update Your model and use ? for

```
public DateTime? DateNTime { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there any other solution? Because I have to change a lot of code to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Well, sorry for the code changes but this is a must do in order to avoid having exceptions. unfortunately, sometimes code leading to exceptions needs to be changed. this is how it is. we can't change that fact by a dirty hack that won't be clear/helpfull and may lead to other issues.